# Where is "~/.gradle" folder in Windows?

Tags: javascript, android, windows, react-native, gradle

I was following the React Native document to create a signed APK.
[Source](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)

> Setting up Gradle variables
>
> Place the my-release-key.keystore file under the android/app directory
> in your project folder.
>
> Edit the file ~/.gradle/gradle.properties and add the following
>
> ```
> MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
> MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
> MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=*****
> MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=*****
> ```

Originally, I thought `~/.gradle` is `<project folder>/android/.gradle`. However, it is not... In the command line, I ran the `cd ~/.gradle/` command and it says:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

Would you please let me know where is this folder (in Windows), so I can create gradle.properties? Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`~` is used to represent the home directory (on unix based systems). When on windows the equivalent would be `C:\Users\username\.gradle` dir. Of course username would have to be changed for your username. This *is* where it is on my computer.